# Run Azure pipeline using devops without a PAT from a .net core application

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

Good day,

Currently I have an c# application running (hosted on azure) that trigger an Azure pipeline with some property's. This solution is currently using a PAT as form of authentication. However we want to step away from a token hosted on someones account. I have been trying to use Azure devops for this using an app registration that we use for another service but no luck so far. I can get an access token but i will always end up with a unauthorized response when making a request. I assume this is the case because there is no application permission available for devops and only delegated.

I have kinda hit a wall with this, is it possible to run devops from the application(application permission) without a signed in user

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to run devops from the application(application permission) without a signed in user

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can use the AAD Service Principal access token for authentication.

Here are the steps:

1.Create AAD Service Principal in **Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> App registrations**

2.Add the AAD Service Principal to the Organization and grant the related permissions. Refer to the steps: [Add and manage service principals in an Azure DevOps organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops#2-add-and-manage-service-principals-in-an-azure-devops-organization)

3.Use the following Azure CLI to get the access token.

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>

$accessToken = az account get-access-token --resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 --query "accessToken" --output tsv
```

Or you can use PowerShell script:

```
$TenantId = ""
$ClientId = ""  
$ClientSecret = ""

#$Resource = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com"
$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$Body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$bearer_token= $token.access_token
```

**Note:** The argument `--resource 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798` is rquired. And the access token is **Bearer token type**

Then you can use the AAD Service Principal access token to run the Azure Pipeline.