# How to trigger pipeline using AAD application

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I can able to trigger build pipeline using PAT(personal access token), but I heard that its not a safe method. So I want to trigger the pipeline through AAD application token.

```
 var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .Build();

var authResult = await confidentialClientApplication
    .AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { scope })
    .ExecuteAsync();

var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;


// Set the base URL for the Azure DevOps REST API
client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{organizationUrl}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/");


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", accessToken);
// Set the content type header
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var request = new JObject();
var resources = new JObject();
request["resources"] = resources;
var repositories = new JObject();
resources["repositories"] = repositories;
var self = new JObject();
repositories["self"] = self;
self["refName"] = "refs/heads/branch";

var variables = new JObject();
request["variables"] = variables;

var Datacenter = new JObject();
Datacenter["value"] = "Datacenter";
variables["Datacenter"] = Datacenter;

//Pass parameter into pipeline
var templateParameters = new JObject();
request["templateParameters"] = templateParameters;
templateParameters["Datacenter"] = "Datacenter";

Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
               
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1", content);

// Check if the request was successful
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run triggered successfully.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Response body: {responseBody}");
}
```

I have created the AAD application,secret and given API permissions for AzureDevops but still I am getting authentication issue. Please help me to resolve the issue or any other alternative for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample, you can check the following points to solve the issue.

1.Since you are using the Service Principal Access Token, you need to set the **Bearer** type in the code.

For example:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
```

2.To use the Service Principal to run the Rest API, you can add the service Principal to Azure DevOps Organization. And set the required permissions to the Service Principal to run the Pipeline.

Refer to the following steps:

Step1: Add the Service Principal in **Organization Settings -> Users-> Add Users**.

Step2: Navigate to Pipelines Security to add the required permission to run Pipeline.

For example:

[image]

Step3:We can use the Service Principal Access token to run the rest api.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Add and manage service principals in an Azure DevOps organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586288/run-azure-pipeline-using-devops-without-a-pat-from-a-net-core-application)